# При форматировании кода CSS в VS Code, после запятой переносит на следующую строку

Tags: css, форматирование

Можно ли убрать перенос строки после запятой?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: После запятой? Или может после точки с запятой?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> чтобы зайти в параметры → раздел "Расширения" → Возможности языка CSS → CSS → Format: Newline Between Selectors → снимайте галочку

[image]

Comment: Не помогло. Форматирование идет через Prettier, может там что-то изменить нужно?

Comment: Prettier не использую, не могу сказать точно. Но опять же в настройках расширения смотрите, скорее всего будет такая настройка.